# JBoss 7 CLI no subsystems available

Tags: java, jboss7.x

We had a somewhat strange situation with one of our production servers and so far I wasn't able to find out what happened. Thus I'm hoping that someone here has an idea of what we could look into.

We had deployed two applications which communicate with one another. While one was responsive the other wasn't or only partially. Since we didn't get any meaningful logging information I tried to change the log level using CLI.

So I connected and tried to access the logging subsystem via `subsystem=logging/...`. And here it is becoming strange: the logging subsystem wasn't available, although it was running as could be seen in our log files. I then executed `read-reasource(recursive=true)` at root level and expected to see something like this:

```
{
   ...
   "subsystem" => {
     ...
      "logging" => ...,
      "web" => ...,
      ...
   }
}
```

That means I expected to get some information on the JBoss' subsystems. But what I got instead was this:

```
{
   ...
   "subsystem" => undefined,
   ...
}
```

That indicates the subsystems might have crashed somehow but the applications where still partially working and if the logging or web subsystems had crashed I'd have expected that neither log statements would be written to the file nor html and jsp pages would be delivered.

After restarting the server all was well again but it's still a bad feeling not to know what happend since that could happen again any time soon.

So the question is: *did anyone experience the same of have any idea what we should look for?*

As I said, I tried to find some info but wasn't successful so far, in part because "subsystem" and "undefined" are quite unspecific words to google for - even when combined with "jboss" :)

Comment: Was this a standalone or domain server? I'm not sure if this was an issue in JBoss AS 7, but there was an issue with WildFly https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-1577.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins it was/is a standalone server. Thanks for the info, I'll have a look into it (we're also using Wildfly instances on some systems so that should come in handy anyways).